# aws api gateway, lambda and node express

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, redirect, lambda

I am trying to deploy my express app on lambda and api gateway. I use Claudia.js to do the job to wrap my express app. Here are my routes:

```
app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.render("hello.ejs");
});


app.get("/redirect", function(req, res){
    res.redirect("/");
});
```

In my hello.ejs, it contains:
   `<a href="/redirect"> redirect </a>`

Then I created a root api "/" with the lambda and hello.ejs is successfully rendered through the api. However, when I click the redirect link, {"message":"Forbidden"} show up.

also the url for the api is somehow modified by aws,     xxxx.com/"deploy stage"/  this one becomes the root route, and when I click the "redirect" link, the url becomes xxxx.com/redirect, which does not make sense.

I modified the url to xxxx.com/"deploy stage"/redirect, and the {"message":"Missing Authentication Token"} showed up.

Please help!

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: not really, I ended up giving up claudia.js and use the serverless framework

Comment: ive made this if helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/44134232/575643